# Deserializing JSON data from Kafka stream - Kafka connect to PostgreSQL

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-kafka-python

I'm streaming topic with Kafka_2.12-3.0.0 on Ubuntu in standalone mode to PosgreSQL and getting deserialization error.

Using `confluent_kafka` from pip package to produce kafka stream in python (works ok):

```
{"pmu_id": 2, "time": 1644329854.08, "stream_id": 2, "stat": "ok", "ph_i1_r": 27.682000117654074, "ph_i1_j": -1.546410917622178, "ph_i2_r": 25.055846468243697, "ph_i2_j": 2.6658974347348012, "ph_i3_r": 25.470616978816988, "ph_i3_j": 0.5585993153435624, "ph_v4_r": 3338.6901623241415, "ph_v4_j": -1.6109426103444193, "ph_v5_r": 3149.0595421490525, "ph_v5_j": 2.5863594222073076, "ph_v6_r": 3071.4231229187553, "ph_v6_j": 0.4872377558335442, "ph_7_r": 0.0, "ph_7_j": 0.0, "ph_8_r": 3186.040175515683, "ph_8_j": -1.6065850592620299, "analog": [], "digital": 0, "frequency": 50.014, "rocof": 1}
```

**Configuration for storing in PostgreSQL**

In my `kafka_2.12-3.0.0/config/connect-standalone.properties` I've added connector and converter:

```
plugin.path=/home/user/kafkaConnectors/confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-10.3.2,/home/user/kafkaConverters/confluentinc-kafka-connect-json-schema-converter-7.0.1
```

I'm executing with:

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/sink-postgres.properties
```

My full `config/sink-postgres.properties` :

```
name=sinkIRIpostgre
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pgdb
topics=pmu1
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
connection.user=pguser
connection.password=pgpass
auto.create=true
auto.evolve=true
insert.mode=insert
pk.mode=record_key
pk.fields=MESSAGE_KEY
```

Getting error:

```
ERROR [sinkIRIpostgre|task-0] WorkerSinkTask{id=sinkIRIpostgre-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:193)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:493)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:473)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:328)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:186)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:241)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error of topic pmu214:
        at io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter.toConnectData(JsonSchemaConverter.java:119)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertKey(WorkerSinkTask.java:530)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:493)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing JSON message for id -1
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:177)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:235)
        at io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter$Deserializer.deserialize(JsonSchemaConverter.java:165)
        at io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter.toConnectData(JsonSchemaConverter.java:108)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.getByteBuffer(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:250)
        at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:112)
```

#### EDIT (Python code)

Here is python code used for generating kafka producer:

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer
..
p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': self.kafka_bootstrap_servers})
...
record_key = str(uuid.uuid4())
record_value = self.createKafkaJSON(base_message)
p.produce(self.kafka_topic, key=record_key, value=record_value)
                p.poll(0)
```

function `createKafkaJSON` is returning `json.dumps(kafkaDictFinal).encode('utf-8')` where is kafkaDictFinal is Python dictionary.

Producer is called in main with:

```
  KafkaPMUProducer(pdc_id=2, pmu_ip="x.x.x.x", pmu_port=4712, kafka_bootstrap_servers ="localhost:9092", kafka_topic="pmu214").kafka_producer()
```

Comment: Please show your Python code

Comment: @OneCricketeer see edit, thanks!

Comment: So, `Producer` class doesn't work with `JSONSchemaConverter`, as answered below. Refer link to Python example below for correct usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're writing straight JSON from your Python app then you'll need to use the `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` converter, but your messages will need a `schema` and `payload` attribute.

`io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter` relies on the Schema Registry [wire format](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format) which includes a "magic byte" (hence the error).

You can learn more in this [deep-dive article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/) about serialisation and Kafka Connect, and [see how Python can produce JSON data with a schema using SerializingProducer](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/json_producer.py)

Comment: Thanks, only thing what worries me  is time in milliseconds: `"time": 1644329854.08`. Should I just convert it to something PostgeSQL supports and mark it 'timestamp'? I should be able to do calculations and alerting based on it latter on in ksql. It's not clear to me what data types are supported with JSON Schema? I see types clearly defined for Avro but I'm not finding same thing for JSON Schema. I assume since JSON is text dict thats why there is not clear spec so  I can use what is supported on other end (PostgreSQL) and it should work?

Comment: I'd suggest you post that as a new question, either here or at https://forum.confluent.io/

Comment: @Hrvoje The valid types spec is here https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.1.1

Comment: You might wanna change avro producer example: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/avro_producer.py according to this bug: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/1078. `schema_registry_client` and `schema_str` should switch places in function call.

Comment: @Hrvoje thanks, I'll check it out